# Fourier Series Relation Time - Frequency

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, fourier-restriction

I want to study and understand the relation between *time* and *frequency* with the help of Fourier Series. Can you indicate me some papers, or some example?

Answer (score 0):

It is more a question of "in what sense does the Fourier Transform capture frequency". I think the best way to understand is to try in practice and see what happens. How the transform behaves. Do you have any software which you could experiment and calculate Fourier Series or transforms with? Here is a small example of what you can do with Octave to experiment to see what parts of a function are added for more and more transform coefficients. In my experience, experiments like this are better to build a knowledge or sense of what a Fourier Series or Fourier Transform is.

[image: Fourier Series]